# Sum(IF) in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, sum

Can I get the sum of bug count with multiple conditions in mysql?

My requirement is, I need to get the sum or the count of bugids having some priority, say P1, which exceed a particular time, but the exceeded count should be calculated from the total count of that particular Priority.

My query is:-

```
select 
sum(
 IF(priority="P1",1,0)) P1, 
sum(
 IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:00:05",1,0))P1_exeeded,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2,
sum(
 IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:00:10",1,0))P2_exeeded,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P4",1,0)) P4count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P5",1,0)) P5count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P6",1,0)) P6count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P7",1,0)) P7count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P8",1,0)) P8count 
from bugs 
where bugs.product_id=237 
and bugs.resolution='FIXED' 
and bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' 
and bug_status="RESOLVED";
```

I got the result as:-

```
------+------------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| P1   | P1_exeeded | P2   | P2_exeeded | P3count | P4count | P5count | P6count | P7count | P8count |
+------+------------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    7 |         19 |    6 |         18 |       5 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+------+------------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I need the sum of the exceeded bug ids from each priority, by taking two conditions in :-

**sum of exceeded bugids above a particular time limit, and its taken from the count of its particular priority category.**

the exceeded sum of bug ids should satisfy both condition in each case.

P1 priority bug ids total I have.
P1_exeeded = IF(timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:00:05",1,0)) taken from the the count of P1 bugids.

Please help to use sum( satisfying 2 conditions) in mysql

Comment: sum(
 IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:00:05") && (priority="P1") ,1,0))P1_exeeded,

Comment: Waww.. It worked chetan :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer. Thanks Chetan.:-

```
select 
sum(
 IF(priority="P1",1,0)) P1,
sum( 
 IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") ,1,0))P1_exeeded,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P2",1,0)) P2,sum( IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:01:00") && (priority="P2") ,1,0))P2_exeeded,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P3",1,0)) P3count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P4",1,0)) P4count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P5",1,0)) P5count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P6",1,0)) P6count,
SUM(
 IF(priority="P7",1,0)) P7count,
SUM(
  IF(priority="P8",1,0)) P8count 
from bugs ....
where
.....
```

```
+------+------------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| P1   | P1_exeeded | P2   | P2_exeeded | P3count | P4count | P5count | P6count | P7count | P8count |
+------+------------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    7 |          1 |    6 |          1 |       5 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+------+------------+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `customer xxx`,
cxType,
`Order Store`,
sum(if(category='xxxx',qty,0)), 
min(`order date`) as 'First Purchcase Date'
FROM table1
group by `customer xxx`;
```

Comment: sql is not strict on indent format, that mean it will be useful if you copy and paste directly into your SQL editor. if you find useless that mean you need to learn more about it

Comment: We have nice markdown language - and special support for all kinds of programming languages. If you have no idea how to utilize these things to create content that works for people (without the need to copy it into a special editor)...  because you just joined this site then maybe you need to learn more about that.

Comment: The only thing I did: mark all your source code, and clicked that {} icon which indents with 4 spaces - which leads to "code" formatting - which also preserves the new lines which you already had in your code. So as said - maybe you consider that there are some things you might want to learn about, too.